# How to categorize/classify functional relationships? [R]

Tags: r, classification, clustering

I have a dataset of bacterial abundance at specific degrees of temperature. Each line is a different bacterial species and each column is the abundance at a specific temperature.

My dataset includes some taxa increasing with temperature, some decreasing, some having plateau at certain values and so on, with several different functional responses of bacterial abundance to temperature.

The question is: how can I classify my bacterial species according to their relationships with temperature? e.g.

- cluster 1 = all species linearly decreasing with temperature;
- cluster 2 = all species linearly increasing with temperature;
- cluster 3 = all species increasing according to a sigmoidal curve;
- cluster 4 = all species increasing according to a saturation curve;

and so on.

Any cool method in R you would suggest?

Answer (score 0):

I would:

1. define a set of temperature-dependence models that you want to test, e.g. linear; exponential, after [Brown et al. (2004)](https://esajournals.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1890/03-9000); Lactin-2; etc. (see [Clarke's](https://oxford.universitypressscholarship.com/view/10.1093/oso/9780199551668.001.0001/oso-9780199551668) and/or [Angilletta's](https://global.oup.com/academic/product/thermal-adaptation-9780198570882?cc=za&lang=en&) books);
2. code them in your favourite modelling software: in R you can use `nls()`, but there might be R packages with ready-to-use implementations of some thermal dependence models;
3. fit each model to the data for each of your study species;
4. select the best model for each study species via [AIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akaike_information_criterion), [BIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_information_criterion), or other model-selection methods.

You can automate the process using loops.

[Here](https://data.marcoplebani.com/testing-the-metabolic-theory-of-ecology-a-worked-example-using-r/) is a blog post I wrote some time ago that might provide some help. It includes a worked example in R.

Comment: Although you discuss regression modeling, you don't respond to the question about classifying the species according to those modeled results.

Comment: If classifying species in this case means grouping them according to their temperature-abundance relationship, to me model selection does the job. If the best model to describe a species' trend is linear, that species belongs to the "linear" group; if the best model is sigmoidal, the species belongs to the "sigmoidal" cluster; and so on. If the goal is to classify them using machine learning or clustering methods, I don't know enough to have a saying.

Comment: I think the key words in the question are the "e.g" and "and so on."  They show that the phrases they enclose offer *examples* of possible outputs.  They do not prescribe the classes beforehand.  The title reinforces this interpretation.  The classes are not determined in advance, but are to be found by analyzing the data.  In other words, how can one cluster a multivariate dataset according to the functional forms of the response variable?  Model selection doesn't do that.  (And if your interpretation were correct, this post would quickly be closed as a duplicate of many threads here.)

Comment: well, @MarcoPlebani proposed a nice workaround that however is not my real goal. Thank you for your alternative though. I agree with whuber, model selection doesn't do that...I need to cluster them: similar function, same cluster

Comment: Package mclust comes to mind. Just putting it out there, even if you probably already know about it. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mclust/vignettes/mclust.html

Comment: Also of possible interest: https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-018-38231-w